# Using Ember, how do I dynamically bind a property in a view helper contained in an each block?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template with code similar to:

```
{{#each item in items}}
   <label>{{item.name}}</label>
   {{view Ember.Select content=selectableValues value={{item.name}}}}
{{/each}}
```

I understand the code above won't work, but it illustrates my problem and what I want to achieve. I don't want to bind what's selected in the Ember.Select to the property of the iterated item, but rather to a controller property of the name of the iterated item's name property.

How might I do this?

Comment: item.name = 'foo', and you want to bind value to the property `foo` in the controller?

Comment: Yes, if it helps to be more clear, item is a Model, items is a RecordArray. I need my controller to have properties named after the name property of item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to dynamically create a computed property, since you are binding the value of the value, unfortunately, this presents problems if you then decide to change the value of the value, but, I'll leave that up to you to play with.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    {{input value=foo}}
    {{view App.BlahView host=controller propName=chacha}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="blah">
    {{view.propValue}}
  </script>
```

Code

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  chacha:'foo',
  foo:'bar'

});

```
App.BlahView = Em.View.extend({  
  templateName:'blah',
  setupDyna: function(){
    var propName = this.get('propName');
     Ember.defineProperty(this, 'propValue', Ember.computed(function() {
         return this.get('host').get(propName);
    }).property("host." + propName));
  }.on('init')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vunureno/1/edit